# logstash extract and move nested fields into new parent field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

If in my log I print the latitude and longitude of a given point, how can I capture this information so that it is processed as a geospatial data in elastic search?

Below I show an example of a document in Elasticsearch corresponding to a log line:

```
{
  "_index": "memo-logstash-2018.05",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "DDCARGMBfvaBflicTW4-",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "type": "elktest",
    "message": "LON: 12.5, LAT: 42",
    "@timestamp": "2018-05-09T10:44:09.046Z",
    "host": "f6f9fd66cd6c",
    "path": "/usr/share/logstash/logs/docker-elk-master.log",
    "@version": "1"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2018-05-09T10:44:09.046Z"
    ]
  },
  "highlight": {
    "type": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@elktest@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1525862649046
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to capture `LON` and `LAT` as its separate field called geospatial data?

Comment: yes, I want to handle lat and lon as geospatial fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first separate `LON` and `LAT` into their own fields as follows,

```
grok {
  match => {"message" => "LON: %{NUMBER:LON}, LAT: %{NUMBER:LAT}"}
}
```

once they are separated you can use mutate filter to create a parent field around them, like this,

```
filter {
  mutate {
    rename => { "LON" => "[location][LON]" }
    rename => { "LAT" => "[location][LAT]" }
  }
}
```

let me know if this helps.

Comment: @AlessioFrabotta, updated the answer :) you can create LON and LAT as separate fields and add a parent field `location`. please read updated answer

Comment: Thanks!
One last question: in the logstash log I see that the location field is this: "location" => {"LAT" => "42", "LON" => "13.5"}
42 and 13.5 are strings, mind I expect numbers otherwise the visualization in Kibana does not work. It's correct ? Alternatively, I should construct the "location" field in this way: "location": "42, 13.5"

Comment: they are not `STRING` since I used type `NUMBER`.

Comment: you can also force type to float like this if its string :) `%{NUMBER:LON:float}`

Comment: Thanks! however I can not see anything on Kibana by setting the Coordinates Map view :(

Comment: in the index I see this:
"location": {
                "properties": {
                  "lat": {
                    "type": "float"
                  },
                  "lon": {
                    "type": "float"
                  }
                }
              },
maybe location should be a geo_point?

Comment: Hi, if you want it to be `geo_point` you can simply change `[location]` to `[geo_point]` in mutate filter.

Comment: no, it's the same thing ... I wanted to say that the data type must be geo_point for the location object